# Printing value from split result Perl

Tags: perl

Here I have a abc.txt file:

```
aaa,1000,kevin
bbb,2000,john
ccc,3000,jane
ddd,4000,kevin
```

Then I want to print out:

```
kevin
john
jane
```

my Perl script is:

```
open (INFILE, $ARGV[1]) or die "An input file is required as argument\n";   
@store=();
while(<INFILE>)
{
chomp();
@data=split(/,/);
#
#
#
  if (%store ne "0")
    {
    print "Printing users:\n";
    foreach $key (keys %store)
    {print $key."\n";}
}
print "Printing users:\n";
    foreach $key (keys %store)
    {print $key."\n";}
}
```

My idea is to store the value into hash and create key to each value. How can I do in the ### line?

Comment: `print $data[-1], "\n";` will print last column.

Comment: how can i store the values into an array?

Comment: http://perlmaven.com/manipulating-perl-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `@store` and then using `%store`. I didn't understand that why you doing that, but the below code will give you desire output. First read the input file, split the data and then remove the duplicates.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $infile = $ARGV[0];
open my $fh, "<", $infile or die "An input file is required as argument: $!";   
my %store;
while(my $line = <$fh>)
{
    chomp($line);
    my @data = split /,/, $line;
    my @removeduplicate = (grep { !$store{$_}++ } @data)[2];
    foreach(@removeduplicate){
        if( $_ ne ''){
            print "$_\n";
        }
    }
}
close $fh;
```

Output:

```
kevin
john
jane
```

Comment: i use your code and i find it is a empty line in the position of second kevin, how can i remove it?

Comment: Because in question you are not printing second `kevin` as output, see the _'then i want to print out'_ part of your question, above code is giving same output as you have mentioned in your question. Do you print all the value of third column of input file?

Comment: sorry,i make it confuce, the output is right but i dont want a empty line there.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm. it depends what do you want. maybe this example will help you:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper; #for debug if you want
my $infile='abc.txt'; #or ARGV[0] whatever it is
my $fh;
open $fh,'<',$infile or die "problem with $infile $@ $!";
my $inputline;
my %Storage;
my @Values;
while (defined($inputline=<$fh>)) {
    chomp $inputline;
    @Values=split ',',$inputline;
    if (@Values != 3) {
        warn "$inputline has formatted badly";
        next;
    }
    #warn if exists $Storage{$Values[1]}; #optional warning for detected duplicates
    $Storage{$Values[1]}=@Values[0,2]; #create hash data
     #duplicates will be removed automaticly
}
close $fh;
print Dumper \%Storage; #print how perl it stores
foreach my $Key (keys %Storage) { #example loop
    print @{Storage->{$Key}},"\n"; #do anything
}
```

I hope this template will be enough for you.